Unable to load p12 certificate
I am unable to load the p12 certificate after adding new certificate here I am using Telegraph server, it is returning nil on at this line :
identity = CertificateIdentity(p12URL: identityURL!, passphrase: ""). 

Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
if secureMode! {
        let caCertificateURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "certificate", withExtension: "der")
        caCertificate = Certificate(derURL: caCertificateURL!)
        
        let identityURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "certificate", withExtension: "p12")
        identity = CertificateIdentity(p12URL: identityURL!, passphrase: "")
        
        server = Server(identity: identity, caCertificates: [caCertificate])
    } else {
        server = Server()
    }

What  could be possible root cause for this?

The error message indicates that identityURL is nil, which means the app could not find the specified .p12 certificate file in the app's bundle. There are several possible root causes for this issue:

The .p12 File Is Missing from the Bundle:
The most common reason for this issue is that the .p12 file is not included in the app bundle. Make sure the file is added to the Xcode project and its "Target Membership" includes your app's target.

Incorrect Filename or Extension:
Double-check the file name and extension specified in the code. Ensure that "certificate" and "p12" match exactly with the actual file name and extension, including case sensitivity.

File Resource Path Issue:
If the file path is dynamically generated or located outside the main bundle, make sure to adjust the file path accordingly.

Bundle Path Issue During Testing:
If this code runs in a testing environment, the bundle might not contain the expected resources. Make sure to reference the correct bundle.



To further debug this issue, add some checks and print statements:
if secureMode! {
    if let caCertificateURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "certificate", withExtension: "der") {
        caCertificate = Certificate(derURL: caCertificateURL)
    } else {
        print("CA certificate file not found!")
    }

    if let identityURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "certificate", withExtension: "p12") {
        identity = CertificateIdentity(p12URL: identityURL, passphrase: "")
    } else {
        print("P12 certificate file not found!")
    }

    guard let identity = identity else {
        fatalError("Failed to load identity from the p12 file.")
    }
    
    server = Server(identity: identity, caCertificates: [caCertificate])
} else {
    server = Server()
}

This code provides more informative error messages, helping identify if the .p12 file is not being found and could guide you toward the root cause.
